# How do I create multiple tasks in Kafka Source Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm new to Apache Kafka and I'm trying to create multiple tasks, each one with a separate purpose. But the source connector method `taskClass()` returns only 1 task class. So how do I create more ?

Comment: Are you writing your own custom Kafka Connect connector? Or you're just wanting to deploy one?

Comment: @Robin Moffatt I'm trying to deploy [this](https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb) mongoDb connector . I want to create different tasks to retrieve specific fields in different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy multiple connector instances, using the plugin you require. You have gone too low-level looking at `taskClass()` etc. If you can't get the data from multiple sources with a single connector configuration, just create additional connector configurations. Each is just config files. One connector = one task (or more, if scaled out).